# Given a rotated rectangle with known center coordinates, width, height, and angle of rotation, how can the coordinates of the bounding box be found?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Say a rectangle is rotated x degrees clockwise around it's center point.

Known: The width/height of the inner rectangle, the center point, and the angle.

Desired: The 4 coordinates of each corner of the bounding box.

How can this be calculated?

[image]

Comment: You just need to know how to compute the corners of the inner rectangle (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2070100/139123). Then you have this question, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339029/139123, and can use its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a rectangle with base $b>0$, height $h>0$ and centroid $O$ has vertices:

$$
V_1\left(-\frac{b}{2},-\frac{h}{2}\right),
\quad \quad
V_2\left(\frac{b}{2},-\frac{h}{2}\right),
\quad \quad
V_3\left(\frac{b}{2},\frac{h}{2}\right),
\quad \quad
V_4\left(-\frac{b}{2},\frac{h}{2}\right)
$$

the vertices obtained by rotating $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ clockwise and translating $O$ in $G(x_G,y_G)$ are:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_i' = x_G + x_i\cos\theta + y_i\sin\theta \\
y_i' = y_G - x_i\sin\theta + y_i\cos\theta \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \text{with} \; i=1,2,3,4\,.
$$

Therefore, once calculated:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& x_{\min} = \min(x_1',x_2',x_3',x_4'),
\quad \quad
x_{\max} = \max(x_1',x_2',x_3',x_4'); \\
& y_{\min} = \min(y_1',y_2',y_3',y_4'),
\quad \quad \; \;
y_{\max} = \max(y_1',y_2',y_3',y_4'); \\
\end{aligned}
$$

the rectangle that contains it has vertices:

$$
A(x_{\min},y_{\min}),
\quad \quad
B(x_{\max},y_{\min}),
\quad \quad
C(x_{\max},y_{\max}),
\quad \quad
D(x_{\min},y_{\max}).
$$